# Simulate covariant return type behavior

Tags: c++

```
class Ancestor{};

class Descendant : public Ancestor{};

class Base
{
public:
   Ancestor foo(void);
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
// Do not redefine foo as : Descendant foo(void);
};
```

I want to write Deriveds foo in a way that when it is called for a Derived object it will return Descendant.I know that this can be done easily with covariant return type usage. But what if i could not use this feature. How can i simulate this feature in the code above?

Comment: As `Base::foo` returns an `Ancestor` by value... you couldn't have a covariant return for `Derived::foo` anyway.  Run-time polymorphism works through pointers or references and virtual dispatch.  Without knowing your real problem, it's hard to know what's useful for you... for example, can you return a reference or pointer to an Ancestor?

Comment: Yes i can. My question is something like "How could i solve this problem in a compiler(like the old ones) that did not support covariant return types"

Answer (score 3):

> I want to write Deriveds foo in a way that when it is called for a Derived object it will return Descendant.

```
// Do not redefine foo as : Descendant foo(void);
```

Since `foo` is returning `Ancestor` by value, the only way to achieve (a limited kind of) covariance is to redefine `foo`. Thus, *the requirements are contradictory*.

C++ supports covariant raw pointer and raw reference results. With smart pointer result types such as `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::auto_ptr` covariance has to be implemented by redefining the public function in derived classes. This is similar to your problem because the covariant function returns by value – not a raw pointer or raw reference – but it’s also different from your problem, in that there is no inheritance relationship between the smart pointer types, but instead up-conversion.

Here's an example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

struct Ancestor{ virtual ~Ancestor(){} };
struct Descendant : Ancestor {};

class Base
{
protected:
    virtual Ancestor* virtualFoo() const
    {
        return new Ancestor();
    }

public:
   auto_ptr<Ancestor> foo() const
   {
       return auto_ptr<Ancestor>( virtualFoo() );
   }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
protected:
    virtual Descendant* virtualFoo() const
    {
        return new Descendant();
    }

public:
   auto_ptr<Descendant> foo() const
   {
       return auto_ptr<Descendant>( virtualFoo() );
   }
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Base    baseObject;
    Derived derivedObject;
    Base&   baseRef     = derivedObject;

    cout << typeid( *baseObject.foo() ).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid( *derivedObject.foo() ).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid( *baseRef.foo() ).name() << endl;
}
```

In the two first `foo` calls the static result type corresponds to the dynamic type, which is what the covariance is all about from the using code’s perspective.

In the last `foo` call the static type of the `foo` result is `std::auto_ptr<Ancestor>`, while the pointee object is of type `Descendant`.

Note that the overriding of the virtual function relies on C++’s built-in support for covariant result of raw pointer type.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 2):

```
Ancestor * Derived::foo
{
// Do whatever
  return new Descendant ( ); 
}
```

If you can use pointers, then just return an upcasted Decendant pointer. The returned pointer will point to a Descendant and, assuming methods are virtual, act like a Descendant as well.

Comment: Yes - the critical point here is that covariant return types were added as an explicit documentation of this simple polymorphic mechanism (allowing for more compiler checks, a more informative return type in the API, possible additional optimisations) - but polymorphism works just fine before the covariant return types were introduced, and retains backwards compatibility.